# Rename factor level based on one or more conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, case

I have three columns.

```
column names : c(Species, Unit, Month)
row 1 : c(KS, AON, *NA*)
row 2 : c(KS, PFC, *NA*)
row 3 : c(BBA, AON, *NA*)
row 4: c(BBA, PF,  *NA*)
...
```

sample data:

```
structure(list(Species = c("KS", "KS", "BBA", "BBA"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("AON", "PFC"), class = "factor"), Month = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I want to change a factor level in Unit based on a condition
In Unit, Where `Species == "KS"` and `Unit == "PFC"`, replace with "AON"

I have tried `case_when`, but this outs NAs in the Unit of other species.

Comment: `ifelse()` is helpful, e.g. `ifelse(Species == 'KS' & Unit == 'PFC', 'AON', Unit)` (don't forget to convert the factor to character before (`as.character`) and back to factor(`as.factor`) after manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Unit = case_when(Species %in% c("KS", "PFC") ~ factor("AON"),
                          TRUE ~ Unit))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Species Unit  Month
  <chr>   <fct> <lgl>
1 KS      AON   NA   
2 KS      AON   NA   
3 BBA     AON   NA   
4 BBA     PFC   NA
```